# How do I create a simple photo gallery with multiple albums/dirs/folders?

Tags: codeigniter, text

Here is the code,

```
    $album = $_POST['album'];
    $album = strtolower($album);

    $upload_config = array('upload_path' => 'assets/uploads/' . $album, 'allowed_types'=>'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', 'max_size' => '2000', 'max_width' => '680', 'max_height' =>
        '435',);

    $this->load->library('upload', $upload_config);

    if (!is_dir('assets/uploads/')) {
        mkdir('assets/uploads/', 0777, true);
    }
    $dir_exist = true; // flag for checking the directory exist or not
    if (!is_dir('assets/uploads/' . $album)) {
        mkdir('assets/uploads/' . $album, 0777, true);
        $dir_exist = false; // dir not exist
    } else {

    }

    redirect('image');
}
```

This code creates folder in path 'assets/uploads/'. Inside uploads there is folder that i created like orginal,desk,bench... so how can i send this folder name in to view ??

Comment: i have created the folder but what i want is to scan the directory where the folder exists and send all the album name in to vieew file

Comment: not getting? Please explain in detail.

Comment: i have edited above please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if else` loop for that...and conditionally change folder name

```
if($album == desk)
         {   
          if (!is_dir('assets/uploads/desk/' . $album)) {
             mkdir('assets/uploads/desk/' . $album, 0777, true);
             $dir_exist = false; // dir not exist
            } else {

              }

           redirect('image');
         }

else if(if($album == bench){
         if (!is_dir('assets/uploads/bench/' . $album)) {
             mkdir('assets/uploads/bench/' . $album, 0777, true);
             $dir_exist = false; // dir not exist
            } else {

          }

           redirect('image');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a path and else system inforamtion of uploaded file use function:

```
$this->upload->data();
```

This is a helper function that returns an array containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded. Here is a tutorial:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html